# Detecting periods in video file where character is speaking

Tags: video, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I'm busy doing a lot of manual labor on some video files and I was wondering if there's a way I could make it easier:

What I'd like to do is take a video file (for example, an episode of Silicon Valley) and detect the parts where a certain character (i.e. Erlich Bachman) is speaking. I'm not too sure how to go about doing this but it would certainly make my job much easier.

My guess to achieve this would go something like this: Train some special kind of neural net with audio files of Erlich's voice, then use ffmpeg to sample parts of the video file, run the samples through the nnet and if the output is positive, make finer searches to find the exact start/end points of the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) and just feed audio frames (or whatever you call that) one by one. You should *not* train it with just audio files of Elrich's voice. You should actually give it a few episodes as input, whenever Elrich is speaking, you set the desired output to `1`, whenver he/she isn't, you set the desired output to `0`. After being trained, the LSTM will output a value between `0-1`; the higher the value, the higher the change Elrich is speaking.

But keep in mind that you need some decent training set to actually have a well-performing neural network. And together with the time and effort put into the development might outweigh the time you spend searching for parts when Elrich is speaking yourself. So take a look at some API's:

[This](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/speaker-recognition) looks like something you might want to use. **You should google Speaker Recognition** and you'll find what you need.